# Bluetooth gamepad doesn't create /dev/input/event

Tags: bluetooth, linux-device-driver, gamepad, debian-buster

I want to use a Gamesir T1d gamepad (Bluetooth) to read it's commands with Python, on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (Buster).

I am able to connect the gamepad via Bluetooth:

```
[CHG] Device C6:86:A1:04:BB:53 RSSI: -78
[bluetooth]# connect C6:86:A1:04:BB:53
Attempting to connect to C6:86:A1:04:BB:53
[CHG] Device C6:86:A1:04:BB:53 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device C6:86:A1:04:BB:53 ServicesResolved: yes
[Gamesir-T1d-BB53]# pair C6:86:A1:04:BB:53
Attempting to pair with C6:86:A1:04:BB:53
[CHG] Device C6:86:A1:04:BB:53 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[Gamesir-T1d-BB53]# info
Device C6:86:A1:04:BB:53 (random)
Name: Gamesir-T1d-BB53
Alias: Gamesir-T1d-BB53
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Unknown                   (00008650-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: bluetooth:v000Dp0000d0110
RSSI: -78
[Gamesir-T1d-BB53]#
```

However, there is no event created under

```
/dev/input/
```

which I would need to read and map the gamepad's commands into Python.

When connecting a Bluetooth mouse, I can see events being created, so this seems to be a gamepad specific issue.

I was already trying xboxdrv, but without success, probably since the gamesir is not listed as supported device? Also, I have no glue if this is just a missing driver issue, or if there is a generic driver which could work, or if this is a driver issue at all.

What I am missing here?

Comment: "Gamesir T1d controller can only be used with Tello. This is a customized controller for UAV flight, not for game operation." https://store.dji.com/product/gamesir-remote-controller If it's a HID gamepad, can you dump the HID report descriptor?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have a bluetooth remote that's having the same problem, can connect but doesnt create an event. Would be great if you have any idea why by now.